# ¿Cómo agregar campos a una tabla con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando agregar campos a una tabla según una cantidad que le pase en un parámetro.

Por ejemplo: ¿cuántos campos va a agregar? ¿3? Bueno, si le digo que 3 campos, que agregue esos 3 campos a la tabla.

Lo hice solo agregándole un campo y funcionó bien, pero ahora no sé cómo hacer para realizarlo de la manera que lo necesito.

Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
function add_campo($campo){

  $campos = "";
  for($i = 1; $i <= $campo; $i++){
    $campos = 'campo' . $i . ' , ';
  }

  $query="ALTER TABLE costo_cuotas ADD COLUMN $campos text NOT NULL";
  $sql = $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

Pero no me hace nada, no agrega ningún campo a la tabla.

Comment: Acabo de darme que esta pregunta no podrá tener nunca una "respuesta correcta" porque el usuario ha dejado stackoverflow :) al menos espero que la respuesta sea de ayuda en un futuro a quien la busque en algún buscador.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código genera incorrectamente la consulta SQL por dos motivos:

- No concatena las cadenas parciales en `$campos`, se sobreescribe el valor en cada iteración.
- El SQL generado sería igualmente incorrecto.

Para un ejemplo de 2 campos, generaría:

```
ALTER TABLE costo_cuotas
  ADD COLUMN campo1 , campo2 text NOT NULL
```

Sin embargo, lo correcto sería:

```
ALTER TABLE costo_cuotas
  ADD COLUMN campo1 text NOT NULL,
  ADD COLUMN campo2 text NOT NULL
```

Tienes dos soluciones: o hacer una consulta por cada campo adicional, o agregar a la cadena toda la definición por cada campo:

Para simplificar el código te propongo esta solución en la que agrego las cadenas a una matriz que luego uno usando como separador una coma:

```
function add_campo($campo) {
  $campos = [];
  for($i = 1; $i <= $campo; $i++){
    $campos[] = 'ADD COLUMN campo' . $i . ' TEXT NOT NULL';
  }
  if (count($campos) > 0) {
    $query = "ALTER TABLE costo_cuotas " . implode(',', $campos);
  }
  $sql = $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

Por cierto, esto sólo funcionaría con una tabla vacía. Si generas un campo nuevo con `NOT NULL` y sin valor por defecto, las filas anteriores no podrían adaptarse al nuevo esquema.

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner $campo entre comillas simple o hacer una concatenacion.

```
 $query="ALTER TABLE costo_cuotas ADD COLUMN '$campos' text NOT NULL";
```

Comment: Los nombres de campos y tablas pueden delimitarse con comillas invertidas (`), y no con comillas simples (delimitador de cadenas).